# Error al intentar hacer consulta en Android

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al intentar hacer una consulta en *Android*. Mi código es el siguiente:

Método para hacer la consulta:

```
 public String c(){ /*ArrayList<String> getItemDetails(){
    ArrayList<String> itemdetails=new ArrayList<String>();*/
    objBD = new Bd(nContext, "Laboratorios", null, 1);
    db = objBD.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Laboratorios WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Laboratorios);", null);
    if(c!=null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String iLab = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Descripcion"));

            //.add(iLab);
            return iLab;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Activity donde quiero mandar la información obtenida:

```
private TextView Lab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Lab=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lab_con);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ConexionBD O1=new ConexionBD(this);
    O1.c();

    Lab.setText(O1.tostring());

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /*String texto ="bien";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, texto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        Intent i =new Intent(this,Labs.class);
        startActivity(i);*/
    }
    public void salir (View view){
        String texto ="Se ha guardado su registro";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, texto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        Intent salida=new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MAIN); //Llamando a la activity principal
        finish();

    }
}
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method        'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

El error completo que me aparece

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oscar.app/com.example.oscar.app.consulta}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.oscar.app.consulta.onCreate(consulta.java:31)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Una pregunta formulada de 10! Bienvenido a SOes. Recuerda darte una vuelta por el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y por [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/)  ^^  +1

Comment: De acuerdo, es de las  ocasiones que se ve una pregunta bien formulada con los datos necesarios para ser *[resuelta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33068/95)*, gracias Oscar, saludos.

Comment: Puedes publicar el xml con el layout?¿

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que definir tu `TextView` así ya que el error te está indicando que estás intentando usar un método de una referencia nula:

```
TextView Lab=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lab_con);
```

Otro problema que se me ocurre es que no tengas ningún `TextView` con ese id (`R.id.lab_con`). Revisa la configuración de tu `XML`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu mensaje de error es correctamente planteado en tu pregunta,

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference

El error no es debido a la consulta, es debido a que estas obteniendo la referencia del `TextView` antes de cargar el Layout que lo contiene:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 Lab=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lab_con); //NO se ga cargado el layout: activity_consulta.xml
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);//Este layout debe ser cargado antes de buscar un widget dentro de el!
.....
```

**Debes cargar el Layout antes de buscar la referencia de un elemento dentro de el**, simplemente asegura que el `TextView` `lab_con` exista dentro del archivo `activity_consulta.xml`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);

    Lab = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lab_con);
.....
```

---

Otro error es similar:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object

Es provocado por el mismo problema primeramente debes cargar el layout contenedor

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);
```

Y posteriormente buscar la referencia del FloatingButton dentro de el, asegura exista dentro de tu layout.

Comment: ya lo he modificado como dices Elenasys. Pero aun continua el error.De hecho me sale mas lineas de error.  Si existe el Text View ya lo revise. Grecias por ayudarme

Comment: @oscarramirez seguramente es el mismo problema, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta, tienes que asegurar cargar primeramente el Layout que contiene los elementos: activity_consulta.xml , revisa y me comentas que resultados obtienes.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es con el `FloatingActionButton` como se puede ver en:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at ...

Verifica que el ID es correcto ya que el `FAB` no se está inicializando correctamente, por tanto al intentar asignarle el `ClickListener` al ser nulo lanza la excepción

Comment: ¿entonces la consulta se debe de mandar desde el activity anterior?, Yo  lo estoy haciendo directamente en  el activity nuevo. Al presionar el boton que me lleve al activity en blanco. ¿Eso es lo que tengo que hacer?

Comment: ¿El FAB está en el layout `activity_consulta`?

Comment: no tengo ningun FAB

Comment: FAB son las siglas de "Floating Action Button"

Comment: elimine el método FAB y me apareció el activity, pero me aparece con un error de código de la base de datos (en el edit text donde debería de aparecer la consulta )y no con la consulta que debería. Lo que imprime es lo siguiente: com.example.app.ConexionBD@20a0c97. (Conexion BD es la clase donde aparecen el método  para la consulta)

Comment: Estas imprimiendo el objeto en sí y no una cadena de texto, si no consigues arreglarlo crea una nueva pregunta y acepta una respuesta en esta